# How to use ajv.addFormat() in postman with javascript

Tags: javascript, json, postman, ajv

I am trying to validate the format of the data request call in postman. The data is of type uuid and relates to property id (shown below).

Would someone please be able to help with this?

This is my code:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);

var Ajv = require('ajv'),
ajv = new Ajv ({logger: console}),
schemaResponse = {
        "required": [
        "id",
        "ID",
    ],
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
         "id": {
            "type": "string",
            "format": "uuidFormatCheck"
         }
};


Code wise it is like this:

var currentSchPmExpTest;

pm.test('Schema is valid', function() {
    //var data = pm.response.json();

    ajv.addFormat('uuidFormatCheck', /^[0-9e-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[1-5][0-9a-f]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12}$/i);

    currentSchPmExpTest = "schemaResponse variable";
    pm.expect(ajv.validate(schemaResponse, jsonData)).to.be.true;
});
```

The body response is:

```
{
    "sfsid": "11c22abc-c11a-1df2-ba3a-123a456b78f1",
};
```

Comment: The schema is invalid and does not match any of the response body that you have added. Can you update the question with the correct details please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the example response body you provided:

```
{
    "sfsid": "11c22abc-c11a-1df2-ba3a-123a456b78f1"
}
```

You could use AJV in Postman like this:

```
let schemaResponse = {
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "sfsid"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "sfsid": {
      "type": "string",
      "pattern": "^(\{{0,1}([0-9a-fA-F]){8}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){12}\}{0,1})$"
    }
  }
};

pm.test('Schema is valid', function() {
    pm.response.to.have.jsonSchema(schemaResponse)
});
```

Comment: Tank you very much for your reply @DannyDainton however this still did not work.

Comment: What doesn't work? You might need to elaborate on that, did you see an error? Can you edit and update your original question with the details.

Comment: sorry, i'm an idiot. It did work, however, it seems, that it only works for this particular piece of JSON file data.

Do you know why would that be?

When I try to use the full schema, of which the sfsid is apart of it does not work.

Comment: I don't know what the rest of the schema / response looks like so I wouldn't know what you're running. That code will only match against the example response body.